# formatting dynamic json array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have an json array as follows:

```
Maindata=[
  {"name":"string1"},
  {"name":"string2"},
  {"name":"string3"}
 ];
```

what I need is an array of following type:

```
data=[
  {
   "name":"string1",
   "name":"string2",
   "name":"string3"
  }
 ];
```

can anybody help me with some methods to obtain required json from original array. 
(note: maindata is json array formed dynamically thats why its structure is like that)

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think what you want as output is a valid object

Comment: why is data not an `object`? why is there an `array`?

Comment: Your second JSON is not valid JSON since object cannot have duplicated name.

Comment: as I said Maindata is obtained dynamically creating html elemnts. like clicking a button so to add textboxes. So key of each element remains same. value String differs for each of them

Comment: please look for my updated question and json

Comment: Why do you need an array of one element, which contains a malformed  "object"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), you can do like following

```js
    var Maindata = [{
      "name1": "string"
    }, {
      "name2": "string"
    }, {
      "name3": "string"
    }];

    var finalObj = Maindata.reduce((acc, cur) => {
      Object.assign(acc, cur);
      return acc;
    }, {})

    console.log(finalObj);
```

Comment: its working if name and string are unique every time as your answer says. but in my case "name" stays same at each element so its returning only last element. can you update your answer. thank you

Comment: You cannot have two properties of a single object with the same name.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) and spread the array elements.

```js
var array = [{ name1: "string1" }, { name2: "string2" }, { name3: "string3" }],
    object = Object.assign({}, ...array);
    
console.log(object);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) or [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to iterate though the items of the `Maindata` object and for each item you can iterate through its keys(using [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)) and group the data into a new structure.(See the below snippet)

**Solution using Array.forEach**

```js
var Maindata=[
  {"name1":"string1"},
  {"name2":"string2"},
  {"name3":"string3"}
 ];
 var result = {};
 var newMaindata=[];
 Maindata.forEach(function(el){
 Object.keys(el).forEach(function(key){
 result[key]=el[key];
 });
 });
 newMaindata.push(result);
 
 console.log(newMaindata);
```

**Solution using Array.reduce**

```js
var Maindata = [{
  "name1": "string1"
}, {
  "name2": "string2"
}, {
  "name3": "string3"
}];
var result ;
var newMaindata = [];
result = Maindata.reduce(function(acc,el) {
  Object.keys(el).forEach(function(key) {
    acc[key] = el[key];
  });
  return acc;
},{});
newMaindata.push(result);

console.log(newMaindata);
```